# Different kind of coin(token) transaction

Tags: transactions

Please help me out.

I want you to fix my problem(Undo or Cancel the transaction) urgently because I'm really desperate at this situation. I'm about to lose all my money.

I mistakenly transfered(withdraw) my Enigma(ENG) tokens(Total Amount : 2805.989) from my Binance exchange(www.binance.com)'s Enigma(ENG) withdrawal address to my Gopax exchange(www.gopax.co.kr)'s Etherium(ETH) deposit address on Jan 19th 21:34.

So, I asked Gopax exchange's technician to fix this problem, but they say they can't help it because the Etherium(ETH) deposit address and Enigma(ENG) deposit address of Gopax exchange is different.

But the weird thing is, apparently, on the Binance exchange, It shows that withdrawal has completed properly.

How could the different kind of coin transaction possibly completed without any warning or notice?

I think the transaction has to be blocked if it was not a same kind of coin address.

And also, as you know, Enigma(ENG) Token adopted ERC20 standards, even If I mistakenly enter my Gopax exchange's Etherium(ETH) deposit address onto the Binance Enigma(ENG) withdrawal address field, It can't be wrong.

Likewise, on the Binance exchange, deposit address of Enigma(ENG) Token and Etherium(ETH) is totally the same.

Then, where is my Enigma(ENG) tokens at?

I'm sending you more detailed transaction information below.

So, please check it out and give an answer.

I look foward to good news from you.

Very thanks.

---

- Txid(TxHash) : 0xd8b77d61269a6987566c3cc92a9abb585efd3f5cd7ffd72c6949f9c2d754f222
- Contract Address(Enigma Token) : 0xf0ee6b27b759c9893ce4f094b49ad28fd15a23e4
- Transfer From : 0x564286362092d8e7936f0549571a803b203aaced → Binance exchange(www.binance.com)'s Enigma(ENG) withdrawal address
- Transfer To(Token Holder) : 0xbbfa6a9597c9faed9a46146e642d27dcc6758199 →Gopax exchange(www.gopax.co.kr)'s Etherium(ETH) deposit address

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Transaction confirmed in the blockchain are final and in practice cannot be reversed. The recipient exchange controls their addresses and are only ones that can recover your tokens. All ethereum addresses can be assigned ether or tokens.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular scenario, the ENG -> ETH Tx went through successfully because of the fact that ENG is an ERC20 compliant token but it will not be credited to your account. However, as both wallet addresses belongs to you and you can prove this, then there might be some hope to ignite a possibility that the exchange will recover your funds (a big maybe)

Not to rub it in but you clearly made the mistake by sending ENG tokens to an ETH address, (exchanges clearly warn you to double check that you're sending to the correct wallet)

I Hope they fix this problem for you, I've seen similar scenarios where they fixed the problem within 4 weeks but it all depends on the exchange and their principles, good luck!